# Optimal approach for large bulk updates to indexed bit sets

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, database-performance, jsonb

The environment for this question is PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on AWS RDS.

The question is about an optimal schema design and batch update strategy for a table with 300 million rows containing the following logical data model:

- `id`: primary key, string up to 40 characters long
- `code`: integer 1-999
- `year`: integer year
- flags: variable number (1000+) each associated with a name, new flags added over time. Ideally, a flag should be thought of as having three values: absent (`null`), on (`true`/`1`) and off (`false`/`0`). It is possible, at the cost of additional updates (see below), to treat a flag as a simple bit (on or off, no absent). "On" values are typically very sparse: < 1/1000.

Queries typically involve boolean expressions on the presence or absence of one or more flags (by name) with `code` and `year` occasionally involved also.

The data is updated in batch via Apache Spark, i.e., updates can be represented as flat file(s), e.g., in COPY format, or as SQL operations. Only one update is active at any one time. Updates to `code` and `year` are very infrequent. Updates to flags affect 1-5% of rows per update (3-15 million rows). It is possible for the update rows to include all flags and their values, just the "on" flags to be updated or just the flags whose values have changed. In the former case, Spark would need to query the data to get the current values of flags.

There will be a small read load during updates.

The question is about an optimal schema and associated update strategy to support the query & updates as described.

Some comments from research so far:

- Using 1,000+ boolean columns would create a very efficient row representation but, in addition to some DDL complexity, would require 1,000+ indexes.
- Bit strings would be great if there was a way to index individual bits. Also, they do not offer a good way to represent absent flags. Using this approach would require maintaining a lookup table between flag names and bit IDs. Merging updates, if needed, works with `||`, though, given PostgreSQL's MVCC there doesn't seem to be much benefit to updating just flags as opposed to replacing an entire row.
- JSONB fields offer indexing. They also offer `null` representation but that comes at a cost: all flags that are "off" would need to be explicitly set, which would make the fields quite large. If we ignore `null` representation, JSONB fields would be relatively small. To further shrink them, we could use short 1-3 character field names with a lookup table. Same comments re: merging as with bit strings.
- `tsvector`/`tsquery`: have no experience with this data type but, in theory, seems to be an exact representation of a set of "on" flags by name. Must use a lookup table mapping flag names to tokens with the additional requirement to ensure there are no collisions due to stemming.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the flags in the main table.

Assuming that the main table is called `data`, define something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE flag_names (
   id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE flag (
   flagname_id smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES flag_names(id),
   data_id text NOT NULL REFERENCES data(id),
   value boolean NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (flagname_id, data_id)
);
```

If a new flag is created, insert a new row in `flag_names`.

If a flag is set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, insert or update a row in the `flag` table.

Join `flag` with `data` to test if a certain flag is set.

Comment: I must add that there is also a performance reason to do this - updates on large rows are slow.

Comment: With 1000+ flags per person, are you suggesting a table of 300 billion rows, with up to 9-45 billion rows updated every time? If you are not suggesting that, i.e., if you want to keep only the flags that are set to "on", why have a value column? Would you expect updating up to 1,000 small rows to be faster than updating one large one?

Comment: Also, I'm curious what does the query for flags `A or (B and C) and not (D and E)` looks like with the schema. Splitting flag information into multiple rows requires extra work to evaluate flag dependencies for the same account.

Comment: I had assumed that only few flags are set; so maybe you'd have to only store the `TRUE` flags after all to make it work. Thousands of columns wouldn't work, and indexing data that are not in first normal form is a pain.

Comment: Querying shouldn't be too difficult: `SELECT data_id FROM flag f_a JOIN flag f_b USING (data_id) JOIN flag f_c USING (data_id) WHERE f_a.flagname_id = $1 AND f_b.flagname_id = $2 AND f_c.flagname_id = $3 AND f_a.value OR (f_b.value AND f_c.value)`

Comment: "indexing data that are not in first normal form is pain"? Isn't that what inverted (GIN) indexes are for? Is that less pain that executing `N` joins or having the entire structure of the SQL statement vary based on the boolean flag expression? I am yet to hear any argument other than "updating larger rows is slower", which needs to be backed by some data when compared to updating several smaller rows, as to why this is a good solution.

Comment: You certainly have a point with the complaint that querying is cumbersome, and I don't know if my solution is workable in your environment. But 1000 columns per table seems like the wrong design to me, particularly if the set of columns changes over time. Perhaps a "NoSQL" solution like `jsonb` would be better for you. I'd build a prototype and experiment with it.